# Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'NSKeyValueChangeKey'

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am getting this error when I am putting this code.

**Error:** Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'NSKeyValueChangeKey'

```
func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
    if !didFindMyLocation {
        let myLocation: CLLocation = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as CLLocation
        viewMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 10.0)
        viewMap.settings.myLocationButton = true

        didFindMyLocation = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Type of `AnyObject` was replaced with type of `Any` in Swift3. So, Tom's answer is correct I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct signature of `observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)` (Swift 4):

```
func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, 
                of object: Any?, 
           change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, 
          context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
```

Regardless of language version, the key for you is to change `change: [NSObject : AnyObject]` to `change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?`.